# TCP/IP SOCKET , ERROR READING ? (LINUX)

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Server and client comminication is working pretty well. But When i write smth to word like " Hello Bro" I only see "Hello" from the server. I know there is a small mistake but i coudent find. I am waiting your helps. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>       //SERVER
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    int sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sock<0){
        perror("Creat Error");
    }
    struct sockaddr_in server,client;

    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port=htons(5000);
    char buff[1024];

    int b = bind(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(server));
    if(b<0) {

        printf("Bind Error");
    }
    listen(sock,5);
    socklen_t clilen=sizeof(client);
    while(1) {

    int clientt = accept(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&client,&clilen);
    if(clientt<0){
        perror("Accept Error");
    }

        int r=read(clientt,buff,1024);

    if(r<0){
        perror("Receave Error");
    }


        printf("%s\n",buff);


        close(clientt);
    }



    return 0;
}
```

And here is the Client

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<netdb.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    int sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sock<0){
        perror("Creating Error");
    }

   struct hostent *host;
   struct sockaddr_in server ;
   server.sin_family=AF_INET;
   host = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");
   server.sin_port=htons(5000);

   if (host<0){
        perror("Host Fail");
    }

    int c = connect(sock,(struct sockaddr*) &server,sizeof(server));
    if (c<0){
        perror("Connection Error");
    }
    char message[100],buff[100];

    printf("Enter Your Message: ");

    scanf("%s",message);

    int s = send(sock,message,strlen(message),0);

    if(s<0){
        perror("Send Error");
    }

    printf("Data is sent");


    close(sock);





 return 0 ;   
}
```

As i said, it sends data but i can only get first word.

Comment: 'printf("%s\n",buff);' OK, first off, go thorugh ALL your server and client code and ensure that all library calls that require a NUL-terminated char array are either eliminated, (preferable), or are only ever called on a char array that is guaranteed to always be NUL-terminated.

Comment: Next, understand what 'SOCK_STREAM' means.  If read() returns with a positive value at all, there is no guarantee that the value will be larger than 1, no matter how many bytes the peer sent.

Comment: Try adding somthing like `fprintf(stderr, "after scanf(): message =  '%s'\n", message)` right after the call the `send()` to the server's code and become enlightened. :-)

Comment: Also reading `read()`'s complete man-page might help.

Comment: Replace `scanf("%s")` with `fgets`.  Does that fix it?

Comment: I changed scanf part , cause it takes only first. and i used "fgets" in stead of that. But this time, even it prints well it does add nonsencial symbols at the end of the sentence.@zwol

Comment: @FurkanAkgün That's because you don't send the nul-terminator for the string, but you don't manually nul-terminate the buffer on the server side either, so printf runs off the end.

Comment: 'add nonsencial symbols at the end' [sigh], 'printf("%s\n",buff);' OK, first off, go thorugh ALL your server and client code and ensure that all library calls that require a NUL-terminated char array are either eliminated, (preferable), or are only ever called on a char array that is guaranteed to always be NUL-terminated.

Answer (score -1):

Looks you are trying to send data in TCP. In TCP data goes in chunk. Though I have not tested your code, I guess, client is sending first word "Hello", and then sending next word "Bro". You can verify this by using wireshark or tcpdump and capturing packets.

Now in your server code I doubt below portion.

```
while(1) {

    int clientt = accept(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&client,&clilen);
    if(clientt<0){
        perror("Accept Error");
    }

        int r=read(clientt,buff,1024);

    if(r<0){
        perror("Receave Error");
    }
```

It received first word "Hello", then it continues while loop, and executes accept. Since no new connections are coming, it is stuck there.

To avoid this you can follow multiple approaches.

Keep accept out of while loop.

OR

Go for async sockets.

I will suggest go for first approach (keep accept out of while loop) and as you learn more on async sockets down the line and try.

**UPDATE**

I just put it in a debugger. Looks while reading data from console, it looks its not reading complete string, its reading the first word only.

So you can correct that part, then you can see the desired result.

Comment: Somebody has given down vote without any explanation. What is wrong here, what I have put.

Comment: Although you are touching a critical point with TCP sockets, which would apply to the OP's code sooner or later, the issue (still) is elsewhere. I didn't DVed you answer, BTW.